# High memory consumption in hana table partitioning

Tags: out-of-memory, partitioning, hana

I have a big table having records around 4 billion ,table is partitioned but i need to perform the partitioning again. while doing the partitioning memory consumption of the hana  system reached to its limit 4TB and started impacting other system.

How we can optimize the partitioning so get completed without consuming that much of memory

Comment: Please provide some more details like HANA version, current table partitioning, target table partitioning, error messages etc.

Comment: Version: 2.3.39v, currently we have 3 partitions now we want 8 partition.No error is observed only memory consumption increased and reach to limit.

Comment: What kind of partitioning do you use? Can you post the table DDL and command you use to repartition?

Comment: Hash partitioning.  Alter TABLE "SLT_SCHEMA"."VBFA" PARTITION BY HASH ("VBELV") PARTITIONS 8

Answer (score 2):

To re-partition tables, both the original table structure as well as the new table structure needs to be kept in memory at the same time.
For the target table structures, data will be inserted into delta stores and later on merged, which again consumes memory.

To increase performance, re-partitioning happens in parallel threads, which, you may guess, again uses additional memory.

The administration guide provides a hint to lower the number of parallel threads:

> **Parallelism and Memory Consumption**
>   Partitioning operations consume a
>   high amount of memory. To reduce the memory consumption, it is
>   possible to configure the number of threads used.
>   You can change the
>   default value of the parameter `split_threads` in the `partitioning`
>   section of the `indexserver.ini` configuration file.
>
> By default, 16 threads are used. In the case of a parallel partition/merge, the
>   individual operations use a total of the configured number of threads
>   for each host. Each operation takes at least one thread.

So, that's the online option to re-partition if your system does not have enough memory for parallel threads.

Alternatively, you may consider an offline re-partitioning that would involve exporting the table (as CSV!), truncating(!) the table, altering the partitioning on the now empty table and re-importing the data.

Note, that I wrote "truncate" as this will preserve all privileges and references to the table (views, synonyms, roles, etc.) which would be lost if you dropped and recreated the table.